# Simultaneous diagonalization of density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, density-operator

I know that if two physical observables can be measured simultaneously, then they commute and therefore will be simultaneously diagonalizable.

But my question is about the density matrix. Its known that a density matrix could be orthogonally diagonalized. But what happens if I have two density matrices of two different states whose representations in a fixed base are not diagonal. Can be simultaneously diagonalized? Why?

An example will be awesome.

Comment: Do they commute with each other?

Comment: I was not thinking on that but now I am reading that this hipotesis is called "classically related states", obviously the answer is yes in that case. Butis there a weaker hipotesis for simultanous diagonalizaton? I beliave there isn´t.

Comment: Actually, I am interesting in the physical interpretation of two states that does not commute, could you give me an example and may be a physical interpretation of whay not commute? Thanks

Comment: Notice that if two matrices/operators/etc are simultaneously diagonalizable, they necessarily commute, as you can see by making the product in their eigenbasis.

Comment: Yes, that why I wrote: "obviously the answer is yes in that case" above. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that if the trace distance of two densities matrices is one, $D(\rho_1,\rho_2)=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}||\rho_1-\rho_2||=1$ then they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks @josephh, I will look for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are after, but consider this trivial pure state example in a 2d Hilbert space,
$$
|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle, \implies \rho=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|= \frac{1}{2}({\mathbb I}+\sigma _3),\\
|\psi'\rangle = (|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}, \implies \rho'=|\psi'\rangle\langle \psi'|= \frac{1}{2}({\mathbb I}+\sigma _1).
$$

- It is evident they do not commute and are not simultaneously diagonalizable.

It’s an [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/prove-that-simultaneously-diagonalizable-matrices-commute) thing.

Comment: iFirst, thanks for the help. Dou you have a physical interpretation of this states, something like "this states can not be created by classical comunication"? and again why?

Comment: Thinking thoughtless thoughts... Stay tuned...